# Select input with other option that displays a text input right next to it

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a select input that has 'other' as one of the dropdown options. When 'other' is selected, I'd like to display a mandatory text input on the same line. Below is a screenshot of my specifications and a fiddle of what I have so far. I would greatly appreciate if someone could double check my html structure, and also provide jquery for toggling show/hide for the input box.

[image: specs]

[myfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ymvkov6/)

```
<div>
    <label for="fixture-use">Fixture Use? *</label>
    <div class="select-style">
    <select name="fixture-use" id="fixture-use" required>
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="hidden-textbox" name="fixture-use" 
           id="fixture-use">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You perhaps forgot to include your attempted JavaScript, have you tried anything, yet?

Comment: u can get value of selected option like `$('#selectID option:selected').val();` and check it onchange of `select` if `value==other`
e.g. `$('#fixture-use').on('change',function(){
if($('#fixture-use option:selected').val()=="other"){}
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned elsewhere, the `id` of an element ***must be unique within the document***; therefore the `id` of the `<select>` and the `id` of the ` must be different.

However, for this to work there's no real need for the `<input>` to *have* an `id`; assuming that the HTML structure is reliable it's possible to traverse from the `<select>` to the `<input>` with jQuery, or plain JavaScript.

That said, I'd suggest the following:

```
// selecting the relevant element, in this case the
// (only) element with the id of 'fixture-use', and
// using the on() method to bind an anonymous function
// as the change event-handler:
$('#fixture-use').on('change', function() {

  // caching the changed-element (the <select>):
  var changed = this,

      // because I want to use the result of this check
      // in two places it makes sense to evaluate the
      // condition once, and then refer to the variable:
      check = changed.value.toLowerCase() === "other";

  // wrapping the changed-element in a jQuery object, to
  // use jQuery methods:
  $(changed)
    // finding the next sibling element:
    .next()
    // toggling the display of that element,
    // to hide and show it depending on the
    // passed-in switch (the Boolean true/false),
    // if true, the element is shown; if false
    // the element is hidden:
    .toggle(check)
    // making the <input> required (if the check
    // is true) or not-required (if the check is
    // false):
    .prop('required', check);

// triggering the change event, causing the event-
// handler to run, on page load; so if the default
// value is 'other' then the <input> will be shown:
}).change();
```

```js
$('#fixture-use').on('change', function() {
  var changed = this,
    check = changed.value.toLowerCase() === "other";

  $(changed).next().toggle(check).prop('required', check);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="fixture-use">Fixture Use? *</label>
  <div class="select-style">
    <select name="fixture-use" id="fixture-use" required>
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="hidden-textbox" name="fixture-use" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z6n4zs4L/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Ids should be unique. Change Id of textbox to `fixture-use-txt` as `fixture-use` is already used by the dropdown as its Id.

Increase `width` of your `div` to `275px` or more, so that the dropdown and textbox come in a single line.

You need to add the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#fixture-use').change(function(){ //on change of dropdown
 if($(this).val() == "other") // check if dropdown value is other
 {
  $('#fixture-use-txt').show();  // show textbox
 }
 else
 {
 $('#fixture-use-txt').hide(); //hide textbox

 }
});
});
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0ymvkov6/2/) for the same. (Using show/hide)

Alternatively, it can be done as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#fixture-use').change(function(){ //on change of dropdown
 if($(this).val() == "other") // check if dropdown value is other
 {
  $('#fixture-use-txt').css('display','inline');  // show textbox
 }
 else
 {
 $('#fixture-use-txt').css('display','none'); //hide textbox

 }
});
});
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0ymvkov6/5/) for the same. (Changing with `css()`)

Comment: _First of all, Ids should be unique._ this is the only answer which demonstrates the issue and provides a solution. but one suggestion it could be displayed `inline` so instead of `show/hide` better to suggest `addClass/removeClass` or use of `.css()` method. +1

Comment: is the css method supposed to be more efficient than hide/show?

Comment: See `.hide()` stores the previous display property just before setting it to none. `.show()` will use that stored property as what to go back to. So, it does some extra work, but unless you're doing tons of elements, the speed difference should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
display:none
```

for the class hidden-textbox, and when the value of the select==other make hidden-textbox display to inline/block.

You can use jQuery to find the changes to select input

Answer (score 0):

You can take an idea from below code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hidden-textbox").hide();
  $("select#fixture-use").change(function(){
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    if(currentVal == "other"){
      $(".hidden-textbox").show();
    }
    else
      $(".hidden-textbox").hide();
  });  
});
```

```css
.select-style{
  display: inline-table;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 252px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: #fff url("images/arrowdown.gif") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.select-style select{
  padding: 5px 8px;
  width: auto;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.hidden-textbox{
  display:inline;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="fixture-use">Fixture Use? *</label>
    <div class="select-style">
    <select name="fixture-use" id="fixture-use" required>
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="hidden-textbox" name="fixture-use" 
           id="fixture-use">
    </div>
  </div>
```